# Removing Duplicated Data after Joining Tables

Tags: sql-server, join, multiple-tables

I've been stuck on this query since a while and don't know how to go forward. The problem is when joining multiple tables: I noticed that the numeric data does not match the numeric data that I expect. This is because for each record in the table with fewer records, the join takes all of the corresponding records from the bigger table.

For example, suppose you have the following tables. The table with fewer records, Available Fruits, has one record for each A, B, C, D, and E. The table with more records, Sales Today, has multiple records each for A, B, C, D, and E.

[image]

Then suppose you use an JOIN to combine the two tables above.

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM [Available Fruits] A
JOIN [Sales Today] B
ON A.[Fruit ID]=B.[Fruit ID]
```

The result is the table below. Notice that the rows from the Available Fruits table are duplicated for every instance the corresponding ID appears on the Sales Today table. i.e, If you place the Inventory and Fruit fields into a new table, this joined table causes the inventory of apples to appear as 375 instead of the expected 75, as shown in the following image.

[image]

Unfortunately I still don't have enough points to post images.

EDIT: So what I´d like to do in SQL is to somehow be able to roll up the "Sales Today" table to the "Available fruits" granularity level so it doesn't get duplicated OR somehow calculate the distribution of Inventory sold per A,B,C,D,E so I can Join the two tables without duplicate what I've explained with the Inventory field.

I really appreciate all your help guys.

Comment: Have you tried SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: It is how the join supposed to work... You forget to ask your question. `I noticed that the numeric data does not match the numeric data that I expect` do you think we can read your mind to find out what you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually posted what you want it to look like.  Try Something like this (I am not in a position to try it right now and I have never done **group by** on joined tables before)

```
SELECT A.[Fruit ID], A.Fruit, sum(B.[Fruits Sold])
from [Available Fruits] A
left outer join [Sales Today] B on A.[Fruit ID] = B.[Fruit ID]
group by A.[Fruit ID], A.[Fruit]
```